# Every locally compact regular space contains a nonempty $G_\delta$-set

Tags: general-topology

In [this page](https://books.google.de/books?id=B785AETmFKEC&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q&f=false) it is claimed that it is clear that every locally compact regular space contains a nonempty compact $G_\delta$-set.

How is it clear?

Comment: Does you def'n of regular include the $T_1$ property? Usage varies on this.

Comment: @user254665 in that case, the space is completely regular but not necessarily Hausdorff. So no, I don't think the author mean that the space is Hausdorff or $T_1$.

Answer (score 2):

If by *regular* you mean what I would call *regular and* $T_1$, fix $x\in X$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$ with compact closure $K$. If $K=\{x\}$, then $K=U$ is open and hence a compact $G_\delta$. Otherwise, let $y\in U\setminus\{x\}$. $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space, so it is normal, and there is a continuous $f:K\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. Let $C=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$; $C$ is a zero-set and hence a $G_\delta$, and since $C$ is a closed subset of $K$, $C$ is compact.

Comment: This proof can be adapted for a non-Hausdorff completely regular space.

Comment: @iranano: If the space isn’t Hausdorff, one has to specify which definition of local compactness is intended.

Comment: if the space is completely regular, it does not matter.

Comment: By the way, I think, having a compact neighborhood is intended in that book. I'm note sure if definitions for local compactness coincide for regular spaces.

Comment: @iranano: I wasn’t able to access the page at Google Books before, but for some reason this time I was. On page $1$ they specify that all topologies are assumed to be $T_1$.

Comment: See my answer below. I hope it is error-free.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [Brian M. Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1618006/293032). Since $X$ is compact and regular, by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space#Examples_and_counterexamples), it is completely regular. So $X$ can be equipped with a uniformity $\cal D$.

Assuming $X$ is nonempty,there is some $x\in X$. $x$ has a compact neighborhood $C$. Thus, $D=\overline{C}$ is a closed compact neighborhood of $x$. If $D=\overline{\{x\}}=\bigcap_{E\in \mathcal D}E[x]$, then $(\forall E\in \mathcal D)(D\subseteq E[x])$. But there is some open $E_0\in \mathcal D$ with $E_0[x]\subseteq D$. Thus, $D=E_0[x]$. Therefore, $D$ is open (and so $G_\delta$), compact and nonempty.

Otherwise, that is, if  $D\ne\overline{\{x\}}$, then there is some $y\in D \setminus\overline{\{x\}}$. Since $D$ is completely regular, there is a continuous function $f:D\to [0,1]$ with $f[\overline{\{x\}}]=\{0\}$ and $f(y)=1$. Let $E= f^{-1}[\{0\}]$. We have:
$$E=\bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N}f^{-1}\left(\left[0, \frac 1n\right)\right)$$
and so $E$  is a $G_\delta$-set. Also $E$ is closed and is contained in the compact set $D$. So $E$ is compact, contains $x$ and is a $G_\delta$-set.